# No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin- http plugin logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am current trying to do a JavaScript post to Logstash by using a tcp input.

**JavaScript Post**

```
 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "http://localhost:5043";
 xhr.open("POST", url, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 var data = JSON.stringify({"test" : hello});
 xhr.send(data);
```

**Logstash config file**

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5043
    }
}

filter{
}

output {
  stdout  { 
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

**Output in console**

```
{
       "message" => "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.611Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "Host: localhost:5043\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.620Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "Connection: keep-alive\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.621Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.622Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "Origin: http://atgdev11\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.623Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.626Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.634Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "Accept: */*\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.651Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "Referer: http://test/Welcome.jsp\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.653Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.719Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
{
       "message" => "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-12-15T09:58:54.720Z",
          "host" => "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "port" => 55867,

}
```

I cant seem to see my json data **{"test" : hello}** passing into logstash could  there be something wrong with my logstash.config file ? Please help

I have also tried the following :

```
input {
http {
port => 5043
}
}
```

I get the following error is broswser :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5043/. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://test/' is therefore not allowed access.

Please guide me in the right direction as to what I need to look at ? I am very new to the ELK stack

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add the `host` within your `tcp` plugin:

```
input {
    tcp {            
         host => "localhost"
         port => 5043
         mode => "server" <-- change if it's a client
    }
}
```

**OR** you should be having the below settings within your ES `yml` as per this [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9031):

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

Hope it helps!